# Posting to route inside server side code

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have this route set up in my server side code:

```
//Recieves facebook login info.
app.post("/login", function(req, res){
var request = req.body;
console.log("IN LOGIN + " + request);
var userInfo = {
    "name":request.name
}

  //Check if user already exists in database.
  con.query("SELECT * FROM user",function(err,rows){
      var existingUsers = rows;
      for(var i = 0 ; i < existingUsers.length ; i ++){
          if(existingUsers[i].name == userInfo.name){
                console.log("USER exists");
                break;
          } else if (i < existingUsers.length-1){
             con.query("INSERT INTO user SET ?",userInfo,function(err, res){
                 if(err){ 
                    console.log("**Error posting todos to database**"); 
                    throw err;
                 }
              });
              console.log("USER created");
              break;
            }
       }
    });
});
```

In another part of my server side code I have this:

```
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
   clientID: 'xxxxx',
   clientSecret: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
   callbackURL: 'http://www.localhost:3000/auth/facebook/todoPage'
},
function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {


  var name = profile.displayName;

  userSession = true;
  done(null,profile); 
 }
));
```

How can i send this name to my route **login** inside my server side code (so I can have access it to it in my **req** variable in the route) in a similar way to which I send stuff to my routes in my client side code:

```
$.post("login", object, function (response){});
```

Comment: Which part of your code do you have this "var name = "Timmy";"? Is it in the same file? what is the scope of this variable?

Comment: @ViniciusZaramella The route set up above, as well as "var name = Timmy" is in the same file (app.js, my server side code). The variable **name** is global.

Comment: So if I the variable is declared before your route definition it is in the scope of you handler function. You should be able to access it directly.

Comment: @ViniciusZaramella Lets say it's not global, what then?

Comment: Is this variable a constant or will it eventually be in a database?

Comment: My plan is this variable will receive a value, and then i send that variable to my route which sends that variable to a mysql database.

Comment: Can you edit your question writing exactly what you want to do? where does this variable come from? What is the request body that the client sends to the backend and what the response expected from the handler function?

Comment: @ViniciusZaramella edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should no try to put something that is not related to the request inside the req argument.

A option is make the name variable inside your app like that.

```
app.facebookName = "foo"
```

This is not very modular and not so different from a global variable.
But if you are keeping everything in the same file (you shouldn't) that is a option.

Another option is splitting your code in another file and export only the variable name from it.

```
//facebook_profile.js
var facebookName = ""
module.exports = {
     setName : function(name){ 
         facebookName = name;
     },
     getName : function(){
         return facebookName;
     }
}
```

In you app.js you can access the name in two different parts of your code like that.

```
var fbProfile = require("facebook_profile.js")
//Recieves facebook login info.
app.post("/login", function(req, res){
   name = fbProfile.getName();
}

passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
   clientID: 'xxxxx',
   clientSecret: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
   callbackURL: 'http://www.localhost:3000/auth/facebook/todoPage'
},
function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {

  fbProfile.setName(profile.displayName);
  userSession = true;
  done(null,profile); 
 }
));
```

I would still go further i try to put the entire passaport thing inside another file.